# Wait for a View to redraw itself before the next line of code is executed

Tags: android, android-view

I have such a piece of code inside an onTouch listener:

```
game.setNextMove(move);
boardView.invalidate();
checkEnd();
computerMove(boardView);
```

I want to have the boardView redrawed before the checkEnd() method is done. How can i force it to do that?

Comment: What is boardView derived from?

Comment: public class BoardView extends View

Comment: Sorry to say this, but as soon as you say "how can I force a redraw", it means your design is wrong.  Please explain **what** you are trying to do and **why** you are trying to do it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to consider your design as mentioned in the comments, having said that you can achieve your goal by using `Post()` on a `handler` to execute `checkEnd()`. The reason this will work is that posting to the main handler will add it to the message queue which has already the call to `Invalidate` in it which will be executed before the call to `Post()` on the handler.

In short you can do:

```
boardView.invalidate();
Handler handler = new Handler()
hanlder.Post(new Runnable(
  @Override
  public void run () {
    checkEnd();
  }
));
```